# How do I create a list with several identical variables without typing each one?(python)

Tags: python, list

I need a list that represents the zodiac calendar. It is part of a small program that accepts user input of birth month and day. Is there a way to do this? I am still in logic diapers and probably still in the womb when it comes to python. I've also already been told that I'm not very pythonic...I am aware.

```
month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June",
     "July","August","September","October","November","December"]


#The following is the list I am attempting to create
#I need it to represent 365 days but I don't want to type
#each zodiac sign thirty times. It would look ridiculous
#and would probably be considered illogical.

zodiac = [['Capricorn']*19,['Aquarius']*30,['Pisces']*30]

#You probably know with out running the above list that it only
#has three elements zodiac[0],[1],[2]... I need it to have 79.
#Is this possible?

dayOfYear= [0,31,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334]
zodiacDay = int

birthmonth = int(raw_input('Enter your birth month(1-12): ')) - 1
while birthmonth <= 12:
    birthday = int(raw_input('Enter your birth day(1-31): '))
    while birthday < 32:
        zodiacDay = dayOfYear[birthmonth] + birthday
        print"""
You were born on the %r day of the year,
which is the %r of %s. Your Zodiac sign is %s.
""" % (dayOfYear[birthmonth] + birthday,birthday,month[birthmonth],
   zodiac[zodiacDay])
    birthmonth = int(raw_input('Enter your birth month(1-12): ')) - 1
```

Comment: You can use ranges. if zodiacDay is larger than March 21 and lower that 19 April, than its Aries, or whatever. To work with dates, check out  time and date related [modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) of python. Or third party [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/) package.

Comment: What this is supposed to represent is a parallel array. Adding several if statements might be out of scope. And modules and packages are out of my scope. However I will look at them. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your main question of how to combine multiple lists containing fixed values:

```
zodiac = ['Capricorn']*19 + ['Aquarius']*30 + ['Pisces']*30
```

etc. This will concatenate the lists of strings, rather than creating a list of lists of strings. There are other ways but in my opinion this is the simplest, and perfectly suitable for this case.

For other suggestions - if you like using the day of the year as an index into a precomputed lists of values, you might find the [`toordinal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal) method of the built-in `datetime.date` class useful.

Using ranges, as Marcin suggests, is generally how I'd solve this kind of problem - store an index of sign values by the earliest day number, and iterate through that list until you find one less than or equal to the day number given. But using a 365-element list to store the values isn't terrible.

If you're doing this as more than just a learning exercise, make sure you think about leap years. I'm not up enough on astrology to know exactly what to recommend there.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you. This is just a learning exercise in which there is no leap year. I'm not quite to ranges yet but I appreciate the suggestion. I will also take a look at the toordinal method and when I get to built-ins, I will look at that as well. This is what I was looking for @Marcin